# Cloud chamber and observations

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics

What are the best ways to use a [cloud chamber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_chamber) to study particles.
What would you gain from observations done in a cloud chamber.

Comment: You wouldn't gain anything from using a cloud chamber there days, it's antiquated technology. Today we would typically use electronic detectors and scintillation and ionization in gases and liquids to detect particles.

Comment: Yeah those are cool but I don't have those in my house. So I was thinking of an affordable way to observe particles. An less you got so ideas?

Comment: It depends on what "particle observation" means to you. If you want to see tracks, then a cloud chamber is probably one of the few DIY projects that one can think of. If you want to detect ionizing radiation, then an ionization chamber is a fairly simple project and so would different types of scintillation detectors be... but they won't give you tracks. Bare in mind that to a physicist the observation of a track is only useful if it can be analyzed. That took a lot more (a large volume magnetic field for instance) than just a cloud chamber, even back in the days.

Comment: You could also look into spark chambers. This is a nice article: "Construction of a Prototype Spark Chamber" by Jack Collins (arxiv.org/pdf/1010.4010). I have seen some of these in action... they make noise and very cool tracks.

Comment: Thanks for the great advice. How would you go about building an iozination chamber

Comment: An ionization chamber is basically a metal can with a wire in it that is connected to a pre-amplifier that can detect very small currents (as in a few hundred electrons). You may have several of these at home in your smoke detectors. To build one it really takes nothing more than a metal can, a wire and a simple circuit... here is a page that I like: http://www.vk2zay.net/article/264. The preamp looks OK to me, even if it won't be that sensitive... if you are willing to add some high voltage, you can build a nice proportional counter, too.

Comment: What you need to buy or make is a diffusion cloud chamber which when set up is continuous in operation over a period of several minutes.   The dry ice might best be made on site by the expansion of carbon dioxide from a cylinder?  As an extension an alpha source might be found in a smoke detector? https://teachers.web.cern.ch/teachers/document/cloud-final.pdf